# Throw doesnot thow to further catch block for exception like "Thread was interrupted from a waiting state"

Tags: exception, try-catch, windows, thread-exceptions

I am working with windows in that exception i.e. "Thread was interrupted from a waiting state" in written in the function and if exception occurs it will throw to parent try catch block. but for this exception throw statement break and does not work further. please provide solution for this as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

to solve this error write try catch block and throw the error in catch block and then write empty finally block . It will automatically throw error to catch and you can easily handle the error.